# Search for string from list into text file c# console

Tags: c#, foreach, visual-studio-2015, console-application, webclient

I need to check if my mac address is exist inside a file that contain many mac address ?

```
        public static string ismac;
        public static bool resultrr;
        string path = Path.GetTempPath()+"555.txt";
        WebClient clienst = new WebClient();
        clienst.DownloadFile(@"http://localhost/test/mac.txt",path);
        string[] ssv = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        foreach (string items in ssv)
        {
            foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
            {
                ismac= nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
                if (items.Contains(ismac) == false)
                {
                    resultrr = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    resultrr = true;
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

i feel confused, any help to get the working interface mac and compaire it with the text file ?

Comment: What is not working with your current code?

Comment: The code continue working even if my mac address is not inside the text file

Comment: This also GetAllNetworkInterfaces , i need to get the one i am connected with

Comment: I am assuming you are checking value of `resultrr` to be true if your Mac address is there and want to stop it, and it always shows false. If that is the case then you need to adjust your foreach and if condition to break when `resultrr` is true. Will post an answer in few minutes.

Comment: Yes i need the bool value to be true if my mac is in the text file, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, if the MAC address is matched it will set resultrr to true and then immediately set it to false again on the next iteration.

If you want it to return true on a single match, you could split this into its own method and just `return true` on the first match.

```
public bool MACFound()
{
    …
    string[] ssv = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    foreach (string items in ssv)
    {
        foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            ismac= nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
            if (items.Contains(ismac) == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If not you at least need to set returnrr to false before the loops begin and delete the assignment to false within the loop. No reason not to break out of the loop early unless you’re doing something else like counting the number of occurrences, though.

Comment: Thanks it works fine when i change items.Contains to items.Equals

Comment: Strange, as far as I know [string.Contains(string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-6.0#system-string-contains\(system-string\)) should also return true if the strings are equal.

Answer (score 2):

My Visual Studio is still updating. I am writing this on notepad, so please excuse typos.

So, with minimum changes to your existing code, this should work -

```
public static string ismac;
public static bool resultrr;
string path = Path.GetTempPath()+"555.txt";
WebClient clienst = new WebClient();
clienst.DownloadFile(@"http://localhost/test/mac.txt",path);
string[] ssv = File.ReadAllLines(path);
foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
    ismac = nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
    resultrr = ssv.Any(x => x.Contains(ismac));
    if(resultrr) break;
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

This should set `resultrr` should have value true if your mac is there in the list.

You should re consider few more things in your code like replacing `WebClient` with `HttpClient`, using `using` statement around your client.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but the code continue even if my mac is wrong or not found in the array from the text file

Comment: Yes it will continue to look for your MAC unless it finds one. If it doesn't it will set `resultrr` as false. Are you printing value of `resultrr`? If not add this line  `Console.WriteLine(resultrr)` before `Console.ReadKey();`

Comment: If it doesn’t find your address it needs to continue until it has searched the entire file (since your address may still be there further towards the end). Once it finishes processing the file it will exit the foreach loop. Like Gaurav says, it’s then up to you to do something with the result, such as adding code to print it to the screen.

Comment: Thanks it works fine when i change items.Contains to items.Equals